# CKeditor two form on page POST data problem

Tags: php, ckeditor

i have 2 form with CKeditor

```
<form id="save_category" class="uk-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea id="editor1" class="uk-textarea" rows="5" aria-label="Textarea" name="description"><?echo $description?></textarea>
</form>

<form id="save_category_en" class="uk-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <textarea id="editor2" class="uk-textarea" rows="5" aria-label="Textarea" name="description"><?echo $description?></textarea>
</form>



<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
CKEDITOR.add  
</script>

<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2' );
CKEDITOR.add 
</script>
```

now im sending data of this 2 forms with this code

```
$(document).on("submit", "#save_category", function(save_category){
 save_category.preventDefault();
 var formData = new FormData(this);
 $.ajax({
 url: 'controllers/object/save_category.php',
 type: 'POST',
 contentType: false,
 cache: false,
 processData:false,
 data: formData,
 success: function(response){  
 $("#result").html(response);
 }  
 });

var formData_en = new FormData($("#save_category_en")[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: 'controllers/object/save_category.php',
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData_en,
    success: function(response){  
        $("#result").html(response);
    }  
});
});
```

the problem is when im using CKeditor, $_POST['description'] of form #2 doesnt send, only textarea field with CKeditor doesnt work. if im disable ckeditor it works. What is the problem?

problem appears only with CKEDITOR

Comment: I remember encoutering the same issue with CKEditor and TextAreas, I'll try make an answer that explain how to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using CKEditor with a textarea in a form, the integration with the parent form element is automatic. CKEditor automatically updates the replaced textarea when the form is submitted, so there is no need to change any server-side code handling form submission after enabling CKEditor on an existing form element1. However, if you are submitting the form data via Ajax, you may need to update the CKEditor instance before submitting the form data. You can do this by calling the updateElement() method on the CKEditor instance associated with the form element you are trying to submit
Source: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/savetextarea.html

```js
$(document).on("submit", "#save_category", function(save_category){
    save_category.preventDefault();
    for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    }
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'controllers/object/save_category.php',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        data: formData,
        success: function(response){  
            $("#result").html(response);
        }  
    });

    var formData_en = new FormData($("#save_category_en")[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'controllers/object/save_category.php',
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: formData_en,
        success: function(response){  
            $("#result").html(response);
        }  
    });
});
```